# Immersed boundary method in FEniCS?

Tags: finite-element, fluid-dynamics, fenics

I have looked at the FEniCS tutorials and documentation but I cannot find any mention to the possibility of implementing an immersed boundary method (IBM) for fluid dynamics.

In particular, I want to develop a solver for the incompressible Navier-Stokes equations of internal flows with elastic walls. I am thinking of using a cartesian mesh with an IBM to avoid remeshing.

Is this possible in FEniCS? If yes, is there any code example or paper to demonstrate the procedure? If no, how tedious would it be to dig into the source code and implement it?

Comment: Did you look at this: https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/4136/147bea8e1c4314da2202ff776f85e316cc27.pdf ?

Comment: I don't know about FEniCS, but deal.II has this program: https://dealii.org/developer/doxygen/deal.II/step_60.html

Comment: @AloneProgrammer No, I hadn't. Thank you for the thesis, seems very relevant.

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth Thank you for the link. After a first glance, test case 1 of this webpage seems to be exactly what I looked for. I will check the software, although I hope to find something relevant in FEniCS.

Comment: There are also more advanced features related to immersed boundaries that will be coming up in dealii. You can look at the following preliminary work https://github.com/dealii/dealii/pull/9078

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth, The example with the distributed Lagrange multiplier (Step 60) is interesting. I am playing around and want to reproduce and compare the test case with Nitche's method for the same Poisson problem. I have written the equations but I don't really know how to handle the cut-cell elements and the boundary terms (what kind of class/functions to use). Is there support for this in deal.ii? Is there any step that reproduces something similar? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth Also, I checked that you have already functions to compute Nitsche's terms (https://dealii.org/developer/doxygen/deal.II/namespaceLocalIntegrators_1_1Laplace.html#aa920ce4642983b9cb2fbf996b75d3c52) but this refers to a computation on the face F, so how the cut-cell is handled in this way?

Comment: @ares I'm not sure there is functionality easily available for cut-cell methods. If I understand them correctly, then you need to augment the set of shape functions for that, right? There is, however, the `FEEnriched` class that might be useful for that.

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth If I understand correctly, the distributed LM method (Step 60) does not use any cut-cell procedure because there is a background penalty field that takes care for the 'cut'. It is true that, from what I am reading, the cut-cell method can be implemented by using a combination of rectangular and triangular elements for the interface cells (but deal.ii supports only rectangular elems?). However, I found this thesis https://uu.diva-portal.org/smash/get/diva2:858026/FULLTEXT01.pdf, proposing a different method, implemented in deal.ii. Unfortunately, the code is not provided.

Comment: Yes, there are numerous publications on the cut FEM on https://dealii.org/publications.html . Search for the word "cut". You might be able to contact some of the authors to see how they implemented things -- I don't know myself.

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth Thank you for the quick answers.